# Many TCPClients in benchmark do not close properly

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I'm currently programing a benchmark for my TCP-Socket Server.
The basic concept is the following:

- The Client creates 10000 connections
- There are 2500 connections concurrent
- They all send 10 seconds ping-pong messages to the server and receive the pong
- After the 10 seconds they all disconnect

When I use smaller numbers of connections (100 concurrent and 1000 connections) everything works fine, but with the setup above, some of the connections remain connected at the server.
This means that the close call never reaches the server at all.

Here is the code for the explanation above:

```
    class Program {   
    static List<Thread> mConnectionThreads_ = new List<Thread>();                  //!< The list of the Threads for all textloaders
    static List<TCPConnection> mConnections_ = new List<TCPConnection>();         //!< The list of TextsXMLParser

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int numConnections = 10000;
        int numConcurrentConnections = 2500;
        for( int k = 0; k < numConnections/numConcurrentConnections; ++k) {
            for( int i = 0; i < numConcurrentConnections; ++i ) {
                TCPConnection connection = new TCPConnection();
                connection.connect(((k+1)*numConcurrentConnections)+i);
                mConnections_.Add(connection);
                mConnectionThreads_.Add(new Thread(connection.pingLoop));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(((k+1)*numConcurrentConnections) + "/" + numConnections + " Threads connected");

            // start all threads
            foreach (Thread t in mConnectionThreads_)
                t.Start();

            foreach (Thread t in mConnectionThreads_)
                t.Join();
            foreach (TCPConnection c in mConnections_)
                c.disconnect();
            Console.WriteLine(((k+1)*numConcurrentConnections) + "/" + numConnections + " Threads disconnected " + cnt + " calls");
            mConnections_.Clear();
            mConnectionThreads_.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The disconnect function looks like the following:

```
    public void disconnect() {
        if(  mClient_.Client != null ) {
            mClient_.Client.Disconnect(false);
            //mClient_.GetStream().Close();
            //mClient_.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("closed " + mConnectionId_);
        }
        else if( mClient_.Client == null )
            Console.WriteLine("closed invalid " + mConnectionId_);
    }
```

As you can see I've already tried a lot of different close methods, but neighter works.

Is there anything I can do in this case? Anybody else having the same issue?

Comment: After you think you close a socket in Windows, it remains in a `TIME_WAIT` (you can view this with TcpView or netstat) for some time before becoming usable.  Also there is a max number of connections in Windows.  There are registry settings to control these.  Finally, do you need to explicitly call `Dispose` on the connection?

Comment: Well, first the tcp-server Runs on an ubuntu server. I have a Thread in the Server program, which Outputs the number of concurrent connected Users. When the Sockets are in a TIME_WAIT State, they should Not be shown there i think. I also have configured the Server to handle more than the default number of 1024 connections so this cannot be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but what type has mClient_.Client?

Usually if you use TCP client (TCPClient class) you can call Close to close the connection. In the same fashion when using directly Socket or NetworkStream you can also call Close.

On the other hand you're detecting and debugging connection open/closed connections on the server, right? There can be the possibility that server code does not handle connection close properly and thus you get incorrect statistics.

Also under heavy load, server may not have enough CPU time to update the state for the connections so you can expect some delays. Does your server uses asynchronous I/O or connection per thread principle?

Comment: In this case it was a problem with the server, but not the server code, more the server and it's network latency or so, because I've tested it on a simple small V-Server -> problem as described, Root-Server -> no problem anymore. Thanks for your suggestion.